# How to get Authorization Bearer Token with curl or other unix tool

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, console

I have a problem with getting Authorization Bearer Token value with unix tool like curl from site.
The problem is that I don't know how to get only this value **7FA733D2E75A962D1FED6D26989550BD**. The value is different every time when i make a request (I mean it is not constant value).
I have necessary information for this request and when i try with some browser with cookie manager and put by hand cookie value it is work and get valid token. 
Cookie value is:

```
mac=00%3A1A%3A79%3A40%3A07%3AFF
stb_lang=en
timezone=Europe%2FParis
```

Request URL is:

```
http://livegopanel.club:8080/portal.php?type=stb&action=handshake&token=&JsHttpRequest=1-xml
```

If I try to automate this job from linux console I am not able to get this token. 
When I capture the tcp flow with wireshark get following information from process of getting valid token.

This is the request to site:

```
GET /portal.php?type=stb&action=handshake&token=&JsHttpRequest=1-xml HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (QtEmbedded; U; Linux; C) AppleWebKit/533.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) MAG200 stbapp ver: 4 rev: 2721 Mobile Safari/533.3
Referer: http://livegopanel.club:8080/c/
Accept-Language: en-US,*
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.8
X-User-Agent: Model: MAG254; Link: Ethernet
Host: livegopanel.club:8080
Cookie: mac=00%3A1A%3A79%3A40%3A07%3AFF; stb_lang=en; timezone=Europe%2FParis
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And this is the response from site:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 22 Feb 2020 09:22:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d538fd5b5e457f16e217ec8cf092ea2de1582363373; expires=Mon, 23-Mar-20 09:22:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.livegopanel.club; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 568fe5eebe337ea4-BUD

{"js":{"token":"7FA733D2E75A962D1FED6D26989550BD"}}
```

I try many variation with curl but not able to get the value. How to build the curl request or have is other way (script written on bash, perl, etc.) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `jq` installed:

```
curl -s http://livegopanel.club:8080/portal.php\?type\=stb\&action\=handshake\&token\=\&JsHttpRequest\=1-xml | jq -r '.js.token'
```

`jq` is a swiss army knife for JSON, if you're going to be working with JSON on the command line, I recommend getting acquainted with `jq`.  You can use https://jqplay.org to test your `jq` filters live.

Otherwise using `sed`:

```
curl -s http://livegopanel.club:8080/portal.php\?type\=stb\&action\=handshake\&token\=\&JsHttpRequest\=1-xml | sed 's/.*token":"\(.*\)".*/\1/g'
```